# JQL query to find a linked issue in another project

Tags: jira, jql

I am looking for the Jira JQL syntax to find issues that have a linked issue in another project. For example in three projects I can find the list of issues that have been resolved in the last 90 days. I would like to find a list of issues in our QA project for the original issues resolved list.

Answer (score 1):

sqluser was close. You don't to have designate a single issuekey, if you use the scriptrunner addon. I don't think there is a way around having it. Up to a recent version it was free so you can simply download that version. It's a must have plugin imho. Here is your query:

```
issueFunction in linkedIssuesOf('resolutiondate > 2015-10-01') and project = QA
```

You can extend the criteria of the search. [Here](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/latest/jira/jql-functions.html#_linkedissuesof) is the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this plugin:

http://www.j-tricks.com/jql-tricks-plugin.html

specifically JQL function

```
linkedIssuesInProject(project,[linkType])
```

but the plugin is not free.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `linkedIssues` function and combine it with project name

Something like this:

```
issue in linkedIssues(XYZ-000) AND project = 'ABC'
```

Comment: Using this would force me to query each Jira item. Does not allow me to select all Jira items that have been resolved in the last x days.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get to the solution I needed with the following:

```
AND issueFunction in linkedIssuesOf("project in (ext_proj_1, ext_proj_2, ext_proj_3)") AND issueLinkType in ("depends on", "is blocked by")
```

I then used this in a dashboard where I showed the filter results and added the "Links" column so that users could see what projects we had external dependencies on.